# New systemd service failing (status=203/EXEC)

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemd, systemctl

I'm quite new to systemd and linux in general, so you'll have to bear with me here.

My service is written as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Master Print Service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cwsLogging02.sh cwsMPS.service mps

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the shell script that I would like to run:

```
Date=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo "$1 service started at ${DATE}" | systemd-cat -p info

while true
do
systemctl is-active $1
IS_SYSTEM_ACTIVE=$?
if [ $IS_SYSTEM_ACTIVE = 0 ]; then
echo "$2 is running."
elif [ $IS_SYSTEM_ACTIVE = 3]; then
echo "$2 is inactive."
else
echo "$2 status: $IS_SYSTEM_ACTIVE"
fi
sleep 5
done
```

The shell script runs fine when I run it directly from the command line, but when I attempt to run `sudo systemctl status cwsMPS` (after starting and enabling), [I get this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Ql0.png)

[I also have this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu3cR.png), but I'm not sure if the two issues are related.

Any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: Could you paste the output of `journalctl -u cwsMPS`

Comment: Is your script really missing the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) on the first line? Is it marked executable

Comment: @jordanm oh my goodness! That was the issue! I've been sitting on this for three days now without even realizing I was only missing the shebang. Thanks so much!